# Terminating a web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have this web worker that appends some paragraphs to a div and its like this

```
var worker1 = new Worker('many.js');
var worker2 = new Worker('many.js');
var worker3 = new Worker('many.js');
var worker4 = new Worker('many.js');

      worker1.onmessage = function (event) {
      function xx(){$(event.data).appendTo('#div_1');}
      setInterval(xx,4000);
      }; 

      worker2.onmessage = function (event) {
      function xx(){$(event.data).appendTo('#div_2');}
      setInterval(xx,4400);
      };


      function killworker(){
      worker1.terminate();
      }
```

This is the many.js file

```
function j()
{return "<p>lorem ispum</p>"}

postMessage(j());
```

I am able to destroy the worker like this

```
worker1.terminate();
```

but i would have liked to wrap that in a function and try and terminate it following a click event from a button

```
<button onClick="javascript:killworker();">stop worker</button>
```

My code doesn't seem to terminate the worker.Why doesn't it work?.

Comment: You don't need `javascript:` in inline event handlers. You need it for the `href` of an `<a>` though, but that's unrelated to you and your code

Comment: I have rectified that,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `killworker` function defined in a broader context? If yes, that is your problem. Try `window.killworker = function() { }` instead of `function killworkers() {}` to explicitely define your function as a global function accessible from any scope.

Answer (score 0):

I had to clearInterval first

My code now looks like

```
var worker1 = new Worker('many.js');
var worker2 = new Worker('many.js');
var worker3 = new Worker('many.js');
var worker4 = new Worker('many.js');

      var timer = 0;

      worker1.onmessage = function (event) {
      function xx(){$(event.data).appendTo('#div_1');}
      timer = setInterval(xx,2000);
      }; 

       function killworker(){
       clearInterval(timer);
      worker1.terminate();
      }

      worker2.onmessage = function (event) {
      function xx(){$(event.data).appendTo('#div_2');}
      setInterval(xx,2200);
      };
```

My button `<button onclick="killworker()">stop worker</button>`